# how does a database distributed across multiple servers maintain session with a web app

Tags: mysql, sql-server, riak

How does a database maintain session in a web app when the database itself is spread across multiple servers? How can I implement such functionality in a custom database?

Comment: My first thought was why not have the web app look after session management? I've no experience with RIAK though so that's why I added a comment.

Comment: The thing is, Riak is a distributed database- thats why I asked this question- how to maintain the same session state across multiple servers is what I want to know. Thanks anyway. It would be nice if you could add to your comment though :)

Comment: I had started writing a comment but it's become more of an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Briefly, some key attributes of Riak that make it trivially clusterable:

1. Key/value data model
2. Constant hash function
3. Data partitions that are independent of physical servers

A web app using Riak for session storage would provide a key corresponding to session, such as a session ID passed around via cookies or a userid. Any server in the cluster can take that key, apply the SHA-1 hash function, and determine which data partitions[*] should have that key, and then route the request to the physical servers which currently have those data partitions.

As membership changes the cluster uses gossip to keep track of who owns which partitions.

[*] To provide for availability, copies of all individual pieces of data are stored on multiple partitions

Answer (score 0):

As I said in my last comment I did start adding this as a comment but that was getting too long-winded so here goes.

I'm used to working with the Microsoft web stack. When I've managed sessions it's usually been done in the web application. The web app goes to the database with questions such as 'Select this from there where this happened' or it says 'store this mapped against this id'. From the brief glance I took of RIAK, and looks to me that if you have four nodes then adding data to one node triggers replication to the other three.

I do know that session state can be maintained in a SQL server database. I've needed to do this when working with load-balancers but all I needed to do was add a  key to the web.config. To try and explain this via an example I have one load balancer distributing web requests to three web servers. These each have an identical copy of a web-app. Most web requests are linked to a session and because of adding the  key then web servers go and get the information from the store in the SQL database.

With a distributed database I would guess that the session information is replicated across all its nodes and therefore the web app can treat RIAK as one source rather than having to specify a particular node.